# Sorting Excel thru Word ~ error 1004

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I access Excel from Word to sort Excel data then display in Word, but I get error: 1004 application-defined...

```
dim exc as object, wb as object

Set exc = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

exc.DisplayAlerts = False

Set wb = exc.workbooks.Open("directory of excel wkbook")


With wb.sheets("sheet1")

    .Activate

    .Cells(1, 3).FormulaR1C1 = "=RAND()"
    .Cells(1, 3).Select

    exc.Selection.AutoFill Destination:=.Range("c1:c290"), Type:=xlFillDefault

    .Range("c1:290").Select
    .Sort.SortFields.Clear
```

ERROR occurs in line below:

```
    .Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=.Range("c1"), _
    SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal

End With
```

'''other code below this is not displayed

It works fine in Excel alone but cannot work with Word?

Answer (score 1):

Word doesn't know the values of Excel constants such as xlAscending etc.

You have three options here:

1. define those in your Word VBA
2. add a reference to the Excel object model in your Word VBA Project
3. use the values of the constants directly (you can find those by typing `? constantNameHere` in the Excel VBA editor Immediate pane and pressing Enter).